# Linux non deterministic behaviour taking input

Tags: c

I have written this function:

```
char* input(char* buffer, FILE* fp)
{
    char* result=fgets(buffer,LMAX,fp);
    if(result!=NULL)
    {
    const unsigned int length=strlen(buffer);
    if(buffer[length-1]=='\n')
        buffer[length-1]='\0';
    }
    return result;
}
```

It just takes in input a line of text if fp is equal to stdin.
I have used it many times and it works.
I take the result of fgets just in the case fp is a FILE pointer, so I have to check that the result is not NULL in the case the stream is not good for input operations.
The problem is that if I use it this way:

```
char buffer[LMAX];  // LMAX = 100, defined constant
input(buffer,stdin);
puts(buffer);
```

If the input is like "#dest :a", the puts prints "#dest", cutting the rest of the string.The big problem is that this function was working and one hour ago (it was identical) if I did take in input a string like "#dest :a" the puts was printing "#dest :a".And nothing has changed.Also if I try debugging and I write this:

```
char* input(char* buffer, FILE* fp)
{
    char* result=fgets(buffer,LMAX,fp);
    puts(buffer);  //prints always "#dest :a"
    if(result!=NULL)
    {
    const unsigned int length=strlen(buffer);
    if(buffer[length-1]=='\n')
        buffer[length-1]='\0';
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that in the function it prints "#dest :a".
This function sometimes works and sometimes not, I'm K.O., I can't stand a non deterministic behaviour, what could be this problem (and probably a bug) dued to?

Comment: What if you initialize the buffer? ``char buffer[LMAX] = {0};``

Comment: what compiler you're using? i'm wondering how could you compile "const unsigned int length=strlen(buffer);"

Comment: @Donotalo What's wrong with `const unsigned int length=strlen(buffer);`?

Comment: @Banthar: this is weird. i thought const variables must be initialized by values at compile time. strlen() doesn't work at compile time. but i tried the code above in VS2010 and found no compiler error!

Comment: @Donotalo As it is an auto variable and thus supposed to live on the stack (in most architectures), it is assigned on every execution (of the function). You confuse that with `static`, which is indeed initialized on compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code several times and Im getting nothing but correct output so i cant reproduce the problem.  I do think I know what the issues is.  try calling

```
    flush(stdin);
```

before your call to input.

Comment: what is this defined to do by the C standard? *hint hint*

Comment: fgets doesn't make the input buffer dirty because it also reads the '\n' character.You are right, the code itself doesn't produce any error.  
I was using a strtok that was altering the content of the original string (for some strange reason).